# The SSL connection could not be established. When deploy Azure App Service

Tags: azure, powershell, ssl

I'm using Powershell to deploy Azure App Service.

Powershell cmdlet is very simple

```
Publish-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $rg  -Name $app_name -ArchivePath $package_path -Force
```

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/publish-azwebapp?view=azps-7.5.0

I successful deployed on my laptop. (Powershell 5.1.19041.1645)
But when i use same command in other machine (Powershell 7.2.2) it will error.

```
Publish-AzWebApp: One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)
```

I already try to run this command but still not work.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'Tls', 'Tls11','Tls12'
```

What can i investigate next?

I use $error[0].exception.innerexception to get error detail.[innerexception screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEYed.jpg)

Comment: What does the inner exception message say? Tack on `-ErrorVariable "myerror"` and checkout `$myerror.innerexception`.

Comment: @codaamok. Thank you . I already added innerexception screenshot.